# software that searches from a word the context of the conversation in a video with the subtitle .srt?

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, video, python

I need an alternative to PlayPhrase, it is not easy to use on my windows 7 x64.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciMEY3moATU

https://github.com/kelciour/playphrase

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a lot to install but it is a lot easier than it sounds:

1. Install download & install [Python](https://www.python.org/).
2. Open a command window and type `pip install moviepy` *if you hit any errors on Windows make a note of the package that gave a problem, download it from the [Unofficial Windows Binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and use `pip install <path_to_downloaded_file>`*
3. It is worth installing the optional dependencies listed [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/moviepy).
4. Run through at least one of the examples on the same page as this will download and install FFMPEG.
5. `pip install videogrep` will install [videogrep](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/videogrep/) *read the details about it [here](https://github.com/antiboredom/videogrep)*.

VideoGrep can search for any of python [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html), [parts of speech](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/mbsp-tags) in a [pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-search) and [hypernym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypernym) searches. Take a look at this [blog](http://lav.io/2014/06/videogrep-automatic-supercuts-with-python/) and [this one](https://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/06/21/some-more-videogreping-with-python/) for some detailed examples. You can even assemble fake speeches such as with this script:

```
words = ["Americans", "must", "develop", "open ", "source",
          " software", "for the", " rest ", "of the world",
          "instead of", " soldiers"]
numbers = [3,0,4,3,4,0,1,2,0,1,0] # take clip number 'n'

cuts = [find_word(word)[n] for (word,n) in zip(words, numbers)]
assemble_cuts(cuts, "fake_speech.mp4")
```

Which produced [this](https://youtu.be/iWRYGULFd_c) video.

As long as the mp4 and srt files have the same name and are in the same folder it can search a single movie or all of the movies in a directory looking for matches and splicing together a movie of those sections.

All of the software above is free, gratis & open source and can run on multiple platforms.